# How to enable JAX-WS client side validation in Metro / WebLogic 11g

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jax-ws, java-metro-framework

I want to enable client side validation of my SOAP messages before sending them to the endpoint.

How can I enable it in my client application running in WebLogic 10.3.6 / Metro provider, preferably using the JAX-WS API?

Metro version is `JAX-WS RI 2.1.6 in JDK 6`.

Here is a sample code of my JAX-WS client:

```
@WebService
public class Client {

    @WebServiceRef(wsdlLocation = "RemoteService.wsdl")
    private RemoteService_Service service;

    public void call() throws Exception {

        RemoteService port = service.getRemoteServicePort();

        // configures authentication
        auth(port);

        // builds request
        Request request = new Request();
        request.setValue(null); // this field is mandatory in server

        // client must validate and raise an exception
        port.someOperation(request);

    }

    protected void auth(RemoteService port) {
        Map<String, Object> requestContext = ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "changeit");
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "changeit");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metro documentation [Client Side Schema Validation](https://javaee.github.io/metro/doc/user-guide/ch04.html#client-side-schema-validation) describes how to do it:

> Proxy needs to be created with SchemaValidationFeature to enable
>   client side validation. Both the outgoing SOAP request and incoming
>   SOAP response will be validated.
>
> Example 4.9. Enabling Proxy with Schema Validation
>
> ```
> import com.sun.xml.ws.developer.SchemaValidationFeature;
> ...
>
> SchemaValidationFeature feature = new SchemaValidationFeature();
> HelloPort port = new HelloService.getHelloPort(feature);
> // All invocations on this port are validated
> ```